# Facebook Application: Uploading multiple images in one post to wall

Tags: facebook, api, curl

How to upload multiple images in one post via api?

Like here:
http://www.facebook.com/SocialCity?v=wall

I have managed to upload only one image via curl request.

curl 
-F "access_token=token_here"
-F "message=message_here"
-F "picture=http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
https://graph.facebook.com/app_id_here/feed

Or it's not possible to post multiple images this way?

Anyone?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this - even if you post it yourself and mark it answered. If you upload multiple posts in one request, does it avoid the problem of facebook posting a separate notification on the user's wall for each photo?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by now with the Open Graph however it seems to apply only to user generated fotos:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple photo upload via one Graph API call is not supported. However you can create individual api calls and batch those in one request described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Answer (score 0):

You can now publish multiple images in a single post to your feed or page:

For each photo in the story, upload it unpublished using the `{user-id}/photos` endpoint with the argument `published=false`

```
curl -i -X POST \
 -d "url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fimages%2Ffb_icon_325x325.png" \
 -d "caption=test%20photo%20upload" \
 -d "published=false" \
 -d "access_token=<user_photos_token>" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/photos"
```

You'll get an ID for each photo you upload like this:

```
{
  "id": "10153677042736789"
}
```

Publish a multi-photo story using the `{user-id}/feed` endpoint and using the ids returned by uploading a photo

```
curl -i -X POST \
 -d "message=Testing%20multi-photo%20post!" \
 -d "attached_media%5B0%5D=%7B%22media_fbid%22%3A%221002088839996%22%7D" \
 -d "attached_media%5B1%5D=%7B%22media_fbid%22%3A%221002088840149%22%7D" \
 -d "access_token=<publish_actions_token>" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/feed"
```

Source: [Publishing a multi-photo story](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#publishing-a-multi-photo-story)