# I want to post multi images with SLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter

### I want to post multi images to Twitter and Facebook with SLRequest.

`SLRequest` has method

```
- (void)addMultipartData:(NSData *)data
                withName:(NSString *)name
                    type:(NSString *)type
                filename:(NSString *)filename;
```

I think this method only send one image.

How to send multi images?
Or can not?

### Add a postscript

My co-worker teach me.

this is Twitter API and Facebook API Question.

#### Twitter API configuration say

[GET help/configuration | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/help/configuration)

```
"max_media_per_upload": 1,
```

so, can not multi photo.

#### Facebook API

[api - Facebook Application: Uploading multiple images in one post to wall - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367570/facebook-application-uploading-multiple-images-in-one-post-to-wall)

and

[Using Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#photos)

may be can with `user_generated`

but how to write with objective-c?

Comment: You actually can post several images in one post through SLComposeViewController for Facebook

Comment: in twitter you can upload multiple images .. check https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update#api-param-media_ids